# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context, while using enums

Tags: swift, enums

So I have the following enum

```
enum Franchise: String {
    case visa = "vi"
    case mastercard = "mc"
    case americanexpress = "ax"
    case diners = "di"
}
```

Then with an object that has a franchise attribute declared as follows

```
var franchise : String?
```

Somewhere in my code I verify the following with

```
 if(paymentCard.franchise! == .visa) {
            self.franchiseLogo.image = UIImage(named: "american_express_icon")
        }
```

And I get an "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error.

Also I have tried doing the same with an switch case statement.

```
switch self.paymentCard.franchise  {
            case (.visa):
                // Something
            case (.mastercard):
                // Something
            case (.americanexpress):
                // Something
            case (.diners):
                // Something
        }
```

But in each case I get an error saying "Enum case 'visa' not found in type 'String'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `franchise` as an `optional String` and you´re trying to match it against the `Enum` type `Franchise` which will cause a **missmatch**.

You can either change the type of your variable from:

```
var franchise : String?
```

To:

```
var franchise : Franchise
```

And use your current code. If you still want to use `String?` on your `variable` franchise, then you need to update your code to the following:

```
if franchise == Franchise.visa.rawValue {

}

switch franchise!  {
case (Franchise.visa.rawValue):
    // Something
case (Franchise.mastercard.rawValue):
    // Something
case (Franchise.americanexpress.rawValue):
    // Something
case (Franchise.diners.rawValue):
    // Something
default:
    break
}
```

So what has changed is that you´re matching your string variables against the `rawValue` of `Franchise`.

Comment: You shouldn't use rawValues in case statements. It's really messy

Answer (score 1):

There is a type mismatch `String` vs. `Franchise`.

Although the raw value is `String` the type of the enum is `Franchise`.

There are (at least) 3 solutions:

1. Check on the raw value (no parentheses around the `if` condition)

   ```
   if paymentCard.franchise! == Franchise.visa.rawValue  {
   ```
2. Create a `Franchise` instance from the raw value

   ```
   if Franchise(rawValue: paymentCard.franchise!)! == .visa  {
   ```
3. Declare `franchise` as `Franchise` and change the related code respetively

   ```
   var franchise : Franchise?
   ```

And no parentheses around cases, too ! - `case .visa:`